# Удаление из строки JSON совпавшего значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть вот такая запись JSON такого вида

```
[{"name":"Книга1","price":"860","img":"KI_OBL_BOOK41.png"},{"name":"Книга2","price":"860","img":"OBL_BOOK41.png"},{"name":"Text1","price":"680","img":OBL_SBORNIK_NPA%20(8)mak.jpg"}]"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить всё строку `{"name":"Книга2","price":"860","img":"OBL_BOOK41.png"}` если в ней есть Книга2 ,совпавшее значение из JSON

```
var cookie = Cookies.get("book")
re = new RegExp("Книга",'ig');
$.each(JSON.parse(cookie), function(i,e){
    if(e.match(re) )
      delete(e)
})
```

Comment: создать массив пустой, пройтись по массиву в котором будете искать совпадения, и если вы не находите совпадение - то добавляете знчение в пустой массив.

Comment: я переписал код, подскажите где не прав

Comment: не правы в удалении элементов. вам надо i-й элемент из массива удалять, а не бесполезный `delete(e)` делать. при этом подходе у вас кстати, удаляться все подходящие записи, а не дубликаты